# Cannot create stored procedure due to malformed syntax, if clause?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Currently I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MasterManagement 
    @ProductId INT,
    @ProductName NVARCHAR(40),
    @SupplierID INT,  
    @CategoryID INT,  
    @QuantityPerUnit NVARCHAR(20),  
    @UnitPrice DECIMAL(10, 5),  
    @UnitsInStock SMALLINT,
    @UnitsOnOrder SMALLINT,
    @ReorderLevel SMALLINT,
    @Discontinued BIT,
    @StatementType VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    IF @StatementType = 'INSERT'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].Products (ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder,   ReorderLevel, Discontinued)
        VALUES (@ProductName, @SupplierID, @CategoryID, @QuantityPerUnit, @UnitPrice, @UnitsInStock, @UnitsOnOrder, @ReorderLevel,   @Discontinued);

        DECLARE @LastInserted INT;
        SELECT @LastInserted = SELECT ScopeIdentity();

        SELECT * 
        FROM [dbo].Products 
        WHERE ProductID = @LastInserted
    END

    IF @StatementType = 'UPDATE'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Products 
        SET ProductName = @ProductName,
            SupplierID = @SupplierID,
            CategoryID = @CategoryID,
            QuantityPerUnit = @QuantityPerUnit,
            UnitPrice = @UnitPrice,
            UnitsInStock = @UnitsInStock,
            UnitsOnOrder = @UnitsOnOrder,
            ReorderLevel = @ReorderLevel,
            Discontinued = @Discontinued
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;

        SELECT * 
        FROM Products 
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    END
END
GO
```

But, at the moment of executing the script, I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server e8535208dabe, Procedure sp_MasterManagement, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server e8535208dabe, Procedure sp_MasterManagement, Line 27
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server e8535208dabe, Procedure sp_MasterManagement, Line 30
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

I don't know and I don't understand why I'm getting this error. So far, I believe my syntax is well formed. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this `(SELECT Scope_Identity())` instead of `SELECT ScopeIdentity()`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MasterManagement 
@ProductId INT,
@ProductName NVARCHAR(40),
@SupplierID INT,  
@CategoryID INT,  
@QuantityPerUnit NVARCHAR(20),  
@UnitPrice DECIMAL(10, 5),  
@UnitsInStock SMALLINT,
@UnitsOnOrder SMALLINT,
@ReorderLevel SMALLINT,
@Discontinued BIT,
@StatementType VARCHAR
AS
  BEGIN
    IF @StatementType = 'INSERT'
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].Products (ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder,   ReorderLevel, Discontinued)
        VALUES (@ProductName, @SupplierID, @CategoryID, @QuantityPerUnit, @UnitPrice, @UnitsInStock, @UnitsOnOrder, @ReorderLevel,   @Discontinued);
        DECLARE @LastInserted INT;
        SELECT @LastInserted = (SELECT Scope_Identity);
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].Products WHERE ProductID = @LastInserted;
      END
    IF @StatementType = 'UPDATE'
      BEGIN
        UPDATE Products SET ProductName = @ProductName,
                            SupplierID = @SupplierID,
                            CategoryID = @CategoryID,
                            QuantityPerUnit = @QuantityPerUnit,
                            UnitPrice = @UnitPrice,
                            UnitsInStock = @UnitsInStock,
                            UnitsOnOrder = @UnitsOnOrder,
                            ReorderLevel = @ReorderLevel,
                            Discontinued = @Discontinued
                        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;
        SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;
      END
  END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you! I was breaking my head because of it.